# Flutter custom nav bar Screen transition

Tags: flutter

I made a nav bar like this using a source from YouTube. How do I do the screen replacement part? I don't even know where to add text to the screen right now.

```
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            child: Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(size.width, 80),
                    painter: BNBCustomPainter(),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    heightFactor: 0.2,
                    child:SizedBox(
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){},
                          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(75, 97,238, 1),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket, color: Colors.white,),
                          elevation: 0.1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
          Container (
              width: size.width,
              height: 80,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    IconButton (icon: Icon (Icons.home , color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 97,238, 1),size: 30,), onPressed: (){}),
```